# Merge two (or more) time stamped data and plot showing the gap(s)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

what is the best way to merge and plot 2 (or more) time stamped data so that the plot includes the gaps between the known data?

For example, I have a cell with time and heart rate values for Monday, and another for Friday. I would like to plot all data from Mon to Friday which includesthe gaps showing nothing was recorded from Tues-Thurs?

So far if I merge the data

```
data = [mon;fri]

% get the time serial numbers
dateInd = 1;
dateString = data(dateIndex);
dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS';
tNum = datenum(dateString{1},dateFormat);
t = linspace(tNum(1),tNum(end),length(tNum));
% get heart rates,
HRIndex = 2;
HR = data(HRIndex);
```

and plot

```
plot(t,HR)
datetick('x','ddd');
```

I obviously get Monday and Fridays data merged into a single plot 2 days long. but I would like to have a plot 5 days long with data only showing on monday and Friday. What is the best way to achieve this?

I hope this makes sense,

Many thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve such effect I usually fill missing data with `NaN`s, like here:

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
y(20:30) = NaN; % there will be a gap from point#20 to point#30
plot(x,y);
```

The reason is that MatLab does not draw plot points where either `x` or `y` data are `NaN`s.
In your case you may add missing time points to your time data (to have corect gap) and `NaN`s to corresponding Y-values.

By the way, why don't you plot two separate plots with X-data of the second one properly shifted?

**EDIT**

Case 1: your x-data is time relative to the start of the day (in 0-24 interval). If you plot them directly they will overlap. You have to add some offset manually, like this:

```
% generate test data
x1 = linspace(0,1,25);     % 25 points per first day
y1 = rand(25,1);
x2 = linspace(0,1,25);     % 25 points per second day
y2 = rand(25,1);

% plot them as two separate plots
% so line style, color, markers may be set separately
XOffset = 3;
figure;
plot(x1,y1,'*k-', x2+XOffset,y2,'*r-');
% plot them as single separate plot
% so line style, color, markers are the same
figure;
plot([x1(:); NaN; x2(:)+XOffset],[y1(:); NaN; y2(:)],'*k-');
% One NaN is enough to insert a gap.
```

Case 2: your x-data have full time information including the date (like MatLab's serial date number, see help on `now` function, for example). Then just plot them, they will be offset automatically.

```
% generate test data
XOffset = 3;
x1 = linspace(0,1,25);         % 25 points per first day
y1 = rand(25,1);
x2 = linspace(0,1,25)+XOffset; % 25 points per second day, with offset
y2 = rand(25,1);

% plot them as two separate plots
% so line style, color, markers may be set separately
figure;
plot(x1,y1,'*k-', x2,y2,'*r-');
% plot them as single separate plot
% so line style, color, markers are the same
figure;
plot([x1(:); NaN; x2(:)],[y1(:); NaN; y2(:)],'*k-');
% One NaN is enough to insert a gap.
```

Also instead of

```
plot(x1,y1,'*k-', x2,y2,'*r-');
```

you may do like this (number of plots is not limited):

```
hold on;
plot(x1,y1,'*k-');
plot(x2,y2,'*r-');
hold off;
```

Comment: Many thanks. I am working on inserting NaNs in the data to fill the space to get the desired result. However, I do not know how I would plot 2 separate plots on one time axis with the second one shifted like you mentioned? any pointers? Thanks again, Jon